# HTML nav-tab not rendering by default; must click on it for it to display

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML code

```
    <nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-text-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-text" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-text" aria-selected="true">Text <span class="badge badge-dark">@GetResultCount()</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-images-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-images" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-images" aria-selected="false">Images <span class="badge badge-dark"></span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-map-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-map" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-map" aria-selected="false">Map <span class="badge badge-dark"></span></a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="nav-text" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-text-tab">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">My Results</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="container" id="MySearchResults">
                    Results should go here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-images" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-images-tab">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-map" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-map-tab">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Map</div>
            <div class="card-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I load the page, even though I set the nav-item to "active" and the tab-pane to "active", this is what I get (screenshot below). In order to get "Results should go here" to show up, I have to click on one of the other tabs and then click back on the "Text" tab.

[image]

However, this is what I want to be displayed. Immediately on page load, "Results should go here" is displayed, and I don't have to click on another tab and click back.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the class `show` on the tab pane you want to be shown by default. This was called `in` in Bootstrap 3.

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">



<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-text-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-text" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-text" aria-selected="true">Text <span class="badge badge-dark">42</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-images-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-images" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-images" aria-selected="false">Images <span class="badge badge-dark"></span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-map-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-map" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-map" aria-selected="false">Map <span class="badge badge-dark"></span></a>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="nav-text" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-text-tab">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">My Results</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="container" id="MySearchResults">
                    Results should go here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-images" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-images-tab">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-map" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-map-tab">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Map</div>
            <div class="card-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, while it works as it is on the screen, adding those external dependencies confuses the formatting of other items in the HTML page. Is this possible to do without the dependencies?

Comment: @Emilia do you mean jQuery and Bootstrap? If you want to use any interactive components of Bootstrap, you need its JavaScript code, which itself depends on jQuery.

Comment: That makes sense. Is it possible to do this with Bootstrap 4.0 and Jquery 3.3.1? Those are the versions we have in our project already, and other pieces rely on these versions. Thank you!

Comment: @Emilia added Bootstrap 4 example. Note that I have also wrapped your tab panes in a `div` as per docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior. Otherwise they would stack on top of each other vertically.

Comment: Also removed the Bootstrap 3 example, as the markup didn't play well with its classes.